# ios - How to make NSDateFormatter use timeZone and dateFormat in a single line in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, timezone, nsdateformatter

I am trying to add the two following elements :

```
timeZone = NSTimeZone(name:"Europe/Paris")
```

&

```
dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
```

to the following line :

```
Label.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle:NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle, timeStyle:NSDateFormatterStyle.FullStyle)
```

I don't find the right way to do that (I don't even know if it is possible?).

Any idea?

Comment: Why? Write readable, debuggable code. You will thank yourself later.

Comment: Thank U for reformating.